# Tabs instead of pivots UWP C#

Tags: c#, tabs, pivot, uwp

I am trying to achieve something looking like the next picture

[image: Tab]

So I looked at this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot) which explains how to code pivot pages.

I managed to do it, but how do they manage to get a tab pane?

For now I have something like this:

```
<Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" SelectionChanged="rootPivot_SelectionChanged" HeaderFocusVisualPlacement="ItemHeaders">
            <PivotItem>
               <!-- Some stuff here -->
            </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Comment: From what I can tell you need to assign the Header property on your PivotItems to get your Tabs.

Comment: Apply the header and create a style for the piviot

Comment: thx, I will close this thread then :)

Answer (score 0):

IDK if you found a way to get the Pivots as desired but here is a great place to start.

See Scenario 3 of the sample from [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlPivot)